# How to use setArgument in FragmentActivity

Tags: android

I am able to use setArgument() for passing data in to Fragment But unable to do same thing in FragmentActivity

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)s to pass data to a `FragmentActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyFragmentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("some_key", "some_data");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it;s  passing null data i am getting null point exception error

Comment: Don't pass nulls, or check for null if you do

Comment: i am passing data but it not going there actually i am passing data from my main activity to mapsactivity which is extended to fragmenr activity